# How to access my AP router GUI or admin page?

Tags: internet-connection

I have two routers “TP Link TL-WR840N” (main router) and 2nd “TotoLink N600R” (secondary router , I have turned it into access point to expand my wifi single coverage).
TPLink router I am using only for internet connectivity (ISP link) and a LAN connection for my laptop.
Totolink I have turned it into a access point which is working perfectly fine , using wifi form it (for my cell phone and other devices).
Query/Issue
Can’t access Totolink GUI/admin page!
TPlink, always opens TPlink GUI (192.168.9.1 changed it) either I use LAN , wifi (TPLink SSID ) or (Totolink SISD).
Please suggest how can I access Totolink GUI/admin page without using a Ethernet cable (to do so I need to physically remove the device)

Comment: You have to have routable IP addresses assigned to each network device in order to access them.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying makes little sense.  I can confirm though that changing the SSID will do nothing to solve your problem).

You simply nee to open a web browser and browse to http://(IP address of the N600R).  If that redirects you, flush your browser cache and try again.   If that does not work, you have stuffed up the configuration of your N600R, and need to reset it so you can discover its IP address.  One of the disadvantages of an AP is that it does not route IP through it (it works at a lower level, routing ethernet packets) so you can't easily find its IP address out if you don't know it or have software that can scan for it.